# How can I find the position in a list where an item differs from the previous item?

Tags: python

```
l1 = [1,2,2,2]
```

In the list above, I know that the element differs in l1[0]. Is there any way to find the position in python?

Comment: To clarify - all the items in the list are the same except for one, and you want to find its position?

Comment: @Mureinik yes please

Comment: Assuming you'd like to find *all* positions where items change, your accepted answer does not work on `[1, 2, 2, 1]`, or not even on `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`.

Comment: Hi Suraj, again, please mention if you only want the *first* occurrence (which seems unlikely) or all occurrences where items change. The question is unclear as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
l1.index(min(set(l1), key=l1.count))
```

EDIT:

The lambda expression `min(set(l1), key=l1.count)` tells us what is the element that occurs the fewest number of times in the list. Then we use `l1.index` to figure out the position of that element in the list.

Comment: getting an error "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: @user3543300 thanks for the solution. Can u please explain it?

Comment: What is the purpose of evaluating `set(l1)` here? IMHO, you can just skip the `set` part and still get exactly same output.

Comment: From the comments of the original question, it seems as though there is only 1 different element in the list. If that is not the case, I can update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
UniqueList, indices = np.unique(l1, return_inverse=True)
print(UniqueList) #Unique elements in List l1
```

array([1, 2])

```
print(indices)  #indices of element in l1 mapped to UniqueList
```

array([0, 1, 1, 1])

Comment: running this on `l = [1 ,2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1]` shows `[1, 2, 3]`, which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: It's correct. UniqueList returns unique elements from list l1. Thus, UniqueList is array([1, 2, 3]) and Indices will return -> array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0]). In this case, indices return index of unique element.  As first element in l is 1, In indices it is 0 (as index of 1 in UniqueList is 0). Fourth element is 3 , in indices it will be 2 (Index of 3 in UniqueList is 2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l1 = [1,2,2,2]

for pos, i in enumerate(l1):
    if l1.count(i)==1:      
        print pos
```

Comment: This tells nothing about changing items. A long list with only two different items can have many changing positions. Would show no match in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to show indexes of ***all*** occurrences where items change:

```
l = [1 ,2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1]

changes = [i for i, n in list(enumerate(l))[1:] if l[i] != l[i-1]]

print(changes)
> [1, 3, 5]
```

This simply compares each item from the list with the previous one, lists where elements differ.

Answer (score 0):

Using a modification of `itertools` recipe `unique_everseen` for a solution that keeps track of new entries in a list.

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse
def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None, per_index=False):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen. 
    Use per_index=True to return indices instead of elements."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower, True) --> 0 1 3 6
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for index, element in enumerate(ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable)):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element if not per_index else index
    else:
        for index, element in enumerate(iterable):
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element if not per_index else index
```

To try it out on your example:

```
list(unique_everseen(l1, per_index=True)) # returns [0, 1]
```